# Custom Framework using static lib - Include of non-modular header inside framework module Xcode 9

Tags: c++, c, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have seen plenty of answers around about the issue but non of them are based on my case and "ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES" does not work either.

I am developing a framework that is an implementation of a C library. The library is [OpenHome](https://github.com/openhome/ohNet) and after compiling it and creating the fat libs I have a folder with all the .a and the headers.

Since It has a folder for "Debug" and "Release", I copy this 2 folders in the root of my project, I import the .a files into my "Link binary with libraries" and, in the "Build Settings" of my target, I set the "Header Search Path" with the location of the headers folder.

for importing all the Headers I need to implement I use a c++ class called "MyHeaders.hpp & MyHeader.cpp", I make the the .hpp pubic and I import it like that in my MyFramework.h (Umbrella file):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdocumentation"
#import "MyHeaders.hpp"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

MyHeaders.hpp:

```
#ifndef MyHeaders_hpp
#define MyHeaders_hpp

#include <stdio.h>


/*** CP -PROXIES- ***/
/** Header That Includes all the CP Related Headers **/
#include "OpenHome/Net/C/CpStack.h"

/** CP Services **/
/*UPnP*/
#include "OpenHome/Net/C/CpUpnpOrgConnectionManager1.h"
#include "OpenHome/Net/C/CpUpnpOrgRenderingControl1.h"
#include "OpenHome/Net/C/CpUpnpOrgAVTransport1.h"

#endif /* MyHeaders_hpp */
```

The error come from each include. I have replaced wit import but it also doesn't work.

It is worth mentioning that this project configuration was the one I used in the project (Single View Application) I started implementing and testing. The only difference was the existence of the bridging header.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a researching i found the issue and the solution

When I am `#include "OpenHome/Net/C/CpUpnpOrgConnectionManager1.h"` this header is either not public or contains non public headers.

The solution for importing this headers in a Swift based framework is to to create a Module.

I have created a folder "MyModuleFolder" in my target folder and I have created a "module.modulemap" file inside that looks like

```
module OHNet[system]{

    header "MyHeaders.hpp"

    export *

}
```

After that, in "Build Settings" -> "Swift Compiler - Search Paths " -> "Import Paths" i have added the location for "MyModuleFolder".

Finally,

```
import OHNet
```

in each swift file

I hope it helps.

Comment: for other people seeing this response, this approach of specifying Import Paths has one big disadvantage. Built framework is tied to specific location on disk specified in the Import Paths property and so if you want to reuse the built binary of the framework, or distribute binary via Carthage or Cocoa-Pods, this won't work.